# Operator Search: 'Free Data' not available in Blender 2.9 anymore?

Tags: interface, fluid-simulation, operator, cache

I have a problem with caching my data when I try to run 'replay mode' for a fluid simulation in 2.9. In the 2.8x versions, you can 'free the data', when you search for `free data` in the *Search tool* by hitting (<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>) but I can't find it in 2.9 versions:

[image]

**Q:** How to run the 'Free Data' operator in Blender 2.9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behavior of the [Operator Search](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/templates/operator_search.html) dialog in 2.9x is to only list the operators that can be found in menus. In order to search for all registered operators, you currently have to enable the [Developer Extras](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/interface.html) option in the preferences.

1. Open the preferences *Edit > Preferences*
2. Switch to the *Interface* tab
3. Enable *Developer Extras*

For more information take a look at the design tasks [T76227](https://developer.blender.org/T76227) and [T74157](https://developer.blender.org/T74157).